Lib folder went missing
Is there any way that I can restore my lib folder after it went missing when trying to push to the git repository? It's not in the git repository either.
I already checked all my commit history. Checked the trash bin, Check Recent Files, reset to Previous Commit etc.

wich editor are you using??

If you are using Android studio. Then select the parent folder. Then right click. Select Local history and then show history. If you are using vs code then go to recycle bin. You can view deleted files there.

i am using vs code and no its not in the recycle bin
